# Where can end-of-day price volume data for Japanese stocks be downloaded or subscribed to?

Tags: historical-data

Yahoo finance and google finance do not provide such data. Where can one download Japanese stock data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to download Japanese stock data report [OHLC/Volume](http://www.tse.or.jp/english/market/data/daily/index.html) directly from the Tokyo Stock Exchange.

The only thing is: The report is in PDF format and involves some parsing, if you are willing to do some quantitative analysis.

A **hack**, however, exists: Download the options/futures daily report. It's a nice CSV file, and it contains an underlying price for ***all*** optionable equities. The format and instructions are on the [same page](http://www.ose.or.jp/e/market/trading_data/option_price) as the daily file.

In the end, you'll need to convert Japanese stock code into a name or ISIN. The reference information is located on [Tokyo Stock Exchange](http://www2.tse.or.jp/tseHpFront/JJK020010Action.do?Show=Show).

Finally, a subscription is available on [xignite](https://www.xignite.com/product/XigniteGlobalHistorical/) site.

Answer (score 1):

SONY
http://stocks.finance.yahoo.co.jp/stocks/detail/?code=6758.T
SONY's historical  data
http://stocks.finance.yahoo.co.jp/stocks/history/?code=6758.T

Answer (score 1):

There is special website where you can download or subscribe to historical data https://www.cqgdatafactory.com/

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer.